# How can I retrieve all comments from all pull request on a 1 git project on dev ops

Tags: azure-devops, comments, pull-request

This is one of the metrics we needed to evaluate our developers coding wise. Previously we can query this when the repository was on Dev Ops TFS and its straightforward and can be queried directly on visual studio but migrating to Dev Ops GIT, not sure how. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you mean code comments, are you looking for all new and modified comments in all files that are part of a Pull Request? Perhaps if you explained how you did it in VSTS and what rules you used, it would be easier to help you convert that to usage with Git.

Comment: Yes. code comments in all files that are part of a pull request.

Comment: I'll send the details tom how this was done on TFS,

Comment: if the repository is TFS, its very straightforward to retrieve metrics Boards > Queries > Shared Queries > (make your own query) but the same query does not work for GIT